# Router wont connect to the internet

Tags: networking, router, internet

I recently Purchased a new router ( Dlink DIR 600M Wireless N150 home router) from an online shopping website. I followed the exact instructions as written on the manual about setting up the router, but unfortunately , the router does not connect to the internet. I am having a cable internet connection with Static IP, and I set the same in the router settings. I also set the windows TCP/Ipv4 settings to obtain ip address automatically, but the problem persisted.I tried the ping command in Windows run, and most of the time I get "Request timed out", and for every 10-15 of request timed out, I get a reply from the server. I called a technician from my ISP, but they did the same thing, and since the problem persisted, they said the router was faulty. I exchanged the router for a new one of the same make and model, but the same thing happened. I have an android phone that does connect to the wifi network but says " Connected, no internet" . As I know very little about Networks and Internet, any help in will be very much appreciated.  I am using Windows 10 pro 64 bit.

Comment: Only your ISP can provide the correct settings, if you can connect to the router from your lan then that side is working and the problem is purely on the uplink side.

Comment: If I set the settings manually as provided by the ISP, the router settings page refuses to open. So I have to keep it to obtain the settings automatically.

Comment: Then something is possibly badly configured on your router, proivde your settings in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments on your question you said:

> If I set the settings manually as provided by the ISP, the router
>   settings page refuses to open. So I have to keep it to obtain the
>   settings automatically.

This makes me think you might be setting the static IP address assigned by your ISP as the address of your "LAN" connection instead of your "WAN" connection.  If that's the case then as soon as you save the changes to your router's IP address on the settings page then the router is no longer reachable using the IP address/subnet your router assigned to your device (ie. 192.168.1.151 or whatever) and the settings page will not load (at least not using the default address you were using before - 192.168.1.1 or whatever).  You may have to use the reset button on your router to recover the original settings to start over at this point.

However, I'm baffled how every 10-15 pings would get through if this were the case.

Another possibility is that your ISP locks their connectivity down to the MAC address of your router - which would naturally be different between the old and new router.  In that case the ISP would need to configure the MAC of your new router as being allowed to communicate with the,  But, I'd expect their technician would have caught this when you talked with them.  (and once again the 10-15th ping response doesn't make sense)